# Can I pipe HTML and post data in one command with Lynx

Tags: lynx

Reading the manual page, it seems like `-post_data` always accepts data from stdin. But I'd like to pipe HTML into lynx, too. Can I do both, preferably using something like

```
$ generate_html | lynx --stdin -dump -post_data='mydata'
```

Comment: Are you trying to POST raw html to the server? Or display the HTML generated by generate_html?

Comment: I'm trying to design unit tests without using a server as localhost or selenium. Basically, I want a feedback loop between phpunit and lynx, where I push HTML and post data to lynx, and get back post data I can feed to my web controller.